# non expire AWS Cognito token

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am developing a mobile app where authentication /Authorization handling by AWS cognito (aws-amplify)
Now as per my design app can work offline next 15 days once login but cognito required to refresh token every 60 min .

How to create refresh token for non expire or expire only in next 15 -20 (configurable ) days ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the refresh token expires 30 days after your app user signs in to your user pool. When you create an app for your user pool, you can set the app's refresh token expiration (in days) to any value between 1 and 3650.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

Comment: You can set Refresh token expiration between 60 minutes and 3650 days.